# Code editing shortcuts

Tags: vb.net

I noticed when I move the cursor over a word in my code vb highlights all the same words in my code. Is there a shortcut to edit all the words at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a refactoring tool.
Visual Studio comes with a very simple Refactoring Tool, available from the Refactor toolbar or from the Refactor context menu.
The function that you are looking for is called Rename and its shortcut is `CTR+R, CTRL+R`
(Means press two times keys CTRL and R)

Other alternatives (not free) are [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)

A good explanation of the refactoring process can be found in [Martin Fowler's book, Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/):

`Refactoring is the process of changing a software system in such a way that it does not alter the external behavior of the code yet improves its internal structure. It is a disciplined way to clean up code that minimizes the chances of introducing bugs. In essence, when you refactor you are improving the design of the code after it has been written.`